# How to change the width of a JComboBox within a JMenu and have it placed on the right side

Tags: java, combobox, width, jmenu

So I have a JMenu that looks like [this](https://www.anony.ws/i/2016/07/31/2.jpg) however I want it to look like [this](https://www.anony.ws/i/2016/07/31/106667.jpg). On the second image the combobox's width is set to 200 and is placed at x cord 440, also the second image is without using a JMenu so it's not what I want. I want the JMenu to position the cbox on it's right end with a width of 200 while still allowing me to place more items on the left side, how can I go about doing this without discarding the JMenu like in the second image?

Comment: Post your code ([MCVE])

Comment: @c0der All it is is a `JComboBox()` added into `JMenuBar()` by `JMenuBar.add()`